# android: sending sms from my app

Tags: android, sms

I have sent an sms from my app, which is successfully done.
My message body is:
 **you are asked to join in audio conference meeting. please call 9196147665,55488#**

The message is successfully sent. After sending the sms, I received the message in the receiving device. I wanted to hyper-link `9196147665,55488#` (including hash and comma) but this did not happen. I got hyperlink upto `9196147665`, but not thereafter(starting from the comma to the hash that is `,55488#` ). How can we set, for the entire number `9196147665,55488#`, as one link, so that, I can make a conference call from the link itself?

Please suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the sms is plain text. The hyperlink which you see, is automatically done by the sms application on your phone. Whenever the sms application sees mobile number or email id, it converts it into a hyperlink. May be when it sees number as "9196147665,55488#"  It doesnt recognize it and does not create an hyperlink.

Alternative can be, if you app is also installed on the other device (receiving device) you can read all incoming sms, filter out sms sent by your app and manually display the message in your app. Then you can do anything you want.